# Why are labels for Mobile and Phone not the same in the API?

Tags: describesobject, label, describes

I asked this question on the Salesforce community but its probably not as active as here so wondering if anyone can shed any information on this;

When getting the labels for the Phone and MobilePhone fields on the REST api they're showing up with labels called 'Business Phone' and 'Mobile Phone' but these labels don't match what the UI shows and was wondering why? I use the labels given off the describes on the API but these don't match for Salesforce itself and was wondering why?

If you were to describe the record types of an object this would then display the correct labels, so I'm a little confused.